# Compose OutlinedTextField -the label no working

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The below code works ok... the only issue is that this line:  `label = {Text(text= "Password")}`
the label does not show up...

```
OutlinedTextField(
        value = password,
        onValueChange = {
            password = it
        },
        placeholder = { Text(text = "Password")},
        label = {Text(text= "Password")},
        trailingIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = {
                passwordvisibility = !passwordvisibility
            }) {
                Icon(
                    painter = icon,
                contentDescription = "Visibility Icon"
                )
            }
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password
        ),
        visualTransformation = if(passwordvisibility) VisualTransformation.None
    else
        PasswordVisualTransformation()
    )
```

[image: picture of the preview in Android Studio]

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected according to [Material Guidelines](https://material.io/components/text-fields):

> Label text should always be visible, moving from the middle of the text field to the top (if the field is selected).

When the text field is empty and unfocused, the label appears in the middle. After it gets focus - the label moves to the top, and the placeholder appears.